# What is the performance of C/C++ allocator in multithread context?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

When memory is allocated using new or malloc, allocator may have to protect itself against re-entrance. I see two ways to do this:

- A big mutex. This solution is simple but have poor performance
- A pool of memory is reserved for each thread. Performance is high but size of pool may be difficult to evaluate.

I think most of allocators use the second method, but I cannot find a proof of this.

Do you know which allocator use which method? Is there any standard about that?

Comment: Most competent allocators today use a combination of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google perf tools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) provide an allocator named *TCMalloc*. This allocator use a pool of memory for each thread (= "thread caching system"). Documentation shows [performance improvements measurements](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) over glibc 2.3.

Glibc use a [pool of memory for each thread since 2.16](http://patchwork.sourceware.org/patch/19042).

Therefore, there are [no more performance differences now](https://lwn.net/ml/fedora-devel/20180726161627.GS22369@redhat.com/):

> Fedora [we] used to use tcmalloc for QEMU for a while. Then we checked performance 
>   again and found that the delta to glibc's native malloc had essentially gone

Also notice that C++ `new` operator call `malloc` function provided by `libc` (= glibc malloc in most cases).

So:

1. No, this behavior is not standardized
2. It use a pool per thread only (and only if) you use glibc >= 2.16, else you can try to compile with TCMalloc.

Comment: Hoard and Intel's TBB Allocator take similar routes to TCMalloc. They use per-thread pool allocators combined with locking mechanisms (on certain code paths) to deal with cross-thread deallocations. Both use multiple allocation pools per thread that dispense fixed-size objects of various sizes, to limit worst-case fragmentation to some fixed percent value. Overall, they have very high performance, however, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "size of pool may be difficult to evaluate"—if that's a reference to determining total amount of memory allocated from the OS, that's easy to track.

Answer (score 0):

All multi threaded program analysis, I made with the `intel parallel studio` (under windows) always show lock event and kernel time due to allocation. 
It means that the C++ new of the VS'08 compiler is mainly using mutex to stay memory coherent.

Each time it become an issue in the software I develop, I try to use RIA idiom and remove dynamic/shared memory, or use a TLS allocator if the memory has only to be use by the thread itself.

Comment: What do you call RIA idiom?

Comment: Excuse me, I made a typo error, I would say RAII ( Ressource Acquisition Is InItialization). but it your case.., "it's a kind of ..". when you instanciate an object, or a thread allocate and initialize all the memory and var you use after. or reduce a the minimum dynamic memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

C++17 begin to specify behavior of allocators in threaded applications:

- [std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unsynchronized_pool_resource) is not thread-safe, and cannot be accessed from multiple threads simultaneously
- [std::pmr::synchronized_pool_resource](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/synchronized_pool_resource) may be accessed from multiple threads without external synchronization, and may have thread-specific pools to reduce synchronization costs. If the memory resource is only accessed from one thread, unsynchronized_pool_resource is more efficient.

Comment: In C, starting with version 2.16, `glibc` provide a pool of memory for each thread: http://patchwork.sourceware.org/patch/19042/